# std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf()) causes crash on redirect

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++14, io-redirection

I was trying to redirect cin to a file in visual studios 2015 but every time it runs the line `std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf())` the program crashes

I am writing C++ 14 on Windows 10. Below is the full code.

```
std::cout << "Filename: " << filename << endl;
try {
    std:ifstream in(filename);
    if (in.rdbuf() == nullptr) cout << "FAILED!!!!" << endl;
    std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf());
    return true;
}catch (exception& e){
    std::cout << "error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return false;
}
catch (...) {
    cerr << "UNKNOWN Exception in parsing file in stream";
    return 2;

}
```

Comment: MayI ask why you want to do this? What is the use-case? What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? Can't you just make a function that takes a reference to a `std::istream` and then you can use *any* input stream (file or `std::cin`)? I'm not saying that doing like this is wrong, just that there might be other ways of solving whatever problem you actually have.

Comment: Also note that you are basically saving a pointer to a local variable. When the scope of the `try` block ends then the object `in` is destructed which means its buffer is too. But you still have a pointer to this (now destructed) buffer which means any attempt to use `std::cin` afterwards will lead to *undefined behavior*. The lifetime of the file object and its buffer must be longer than you intend to use it.

Comment: You are very right on that scooping. I moved things around but it was not working out so I went with another approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone finding this issue interesting 6 years later, I had a similar problem trying to redirect standard output (`cerr`, in my case, but `cout` and `clog` work the same) to a file, which worked well *BUT* caused my program to crash with segfault when reaching end of main().

I had to restore the standard output before exiting main() to solve the issue, here's my code:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::ofstream err;
  std::streambuf *oldbuf = nullptr;
  if (some_condition)
  {
    err = std::ofstream(argv[4]);
    oldbuf = std::cerr.rdbuf(err.rdbuf());
  }

  /** incredible code.png **/

  // Close the redirection ofstream (if used)
  if (err.is_open())
  { err.close(); }

  // Restore cerr stream buffer (else: segfault!)
  if (oldbuf)
  { std::cerr.rdbuf(oldbuf); }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that `std::cerr.rdbuf()` returns a pointer to the stream buffer **before the call**, hence the `oldbuf = std::cerr.rdbuf(err.rdbuf());` line.

I hope this will be useful to someone :)